# How to prove a function is continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

What is a general outline of a proof of the continuity of a function? My background is Calculus 2. I think it uses the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, but I only have a very vague idea of what that is.

Comment: It is $\epsilon$ **hyphen** $\delta$, not $\epsilon$ **minus** $\delta$.

Comment: Also, there are hundreds of questions on this site where people ask how to prove that a given function is continuous. Have you taken a look at any of them? Have you taken a look at [the Wikipedia page on continuous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)?

Comment: Also see [Proving Continuity with Open Sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/378237/264), [What's wrong with this definition of continuity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/96324/264), [Understanding the definition of continuity between metric spaces.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/146739/264) for starters.

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~reinholz/ed/07fa_m155/lectures/continuous_functions.pdf. You'll see that you can often bypass a epsilon delta proof.